# How to enable Zpanel php function proc_open

Tags: proc-open

I have one VPS server with Zpanel.
I want to enable proc_open function.
I search disable_functions in php.ini file but there is nothing.
My Script say that this function is disabled.
how to fix this problem?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your domain into
/etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd-vhosts.conf